# Why is my application returning the IIS 404 page on my dev environment but not test or production?

Tags: c#, iis, http-status-code-404

OK, so I develop my application locally at http://dev.myapplication.com (using hosts file for the DNS), and then I have http://test.myapplication.com and http://www.myapplication.com.

In IIS 7 (same version, dev test and live), I've opened 'Error Pages' and edited the 404 status code to go to path '/en/404.mvc'.  This works locally and I can navigate to http://dev.myapplication.com/non-existent-url.mvc which produces the 404 page.

However, if I navigate to http://dev.myapplication.com/non-existent-url (ie a static address) it shows the IIS 404 page and says it was handled by the static file handler rather than my mvc file handler.

I'm baffled as to why this happens, as it has successfully modified my web.config which in turn allows it to work on test and live, just not locally.  i.e. http://www.myapplication.com/404 will show my customized 404 page

Comment: Is your local application pool set to integrated mode?

Comment: no, classic, it's set to classic on each environment

Comment: Ah - have you got a wildcard mapping to run all requests through the aspnet_isapi process? Integrated mode takes care of that but you have to do some extra jumps in classic mode. Are the 3 sites all hosted on the same server?

Comment: Yeh, I've just had a look through all the handler mappings and they are the same on each server.  I had to add *.mvc to make it hit  aspnet_isapi, however everything else is left as default.  I have 3 servers, dev, test, and live, and it just doesn't work on dev.  The only difference I can think of is that locally I'm running Windows 7 whereas the two other servers are Windows Server 2008

Comment: You may be running a different version of IIS. Windows 7 runs IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 runs IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 runs IIS 7.5. I'd add a wildcard mapping as per the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need a wildcard mapping to run all requests through aspnet_isapi - this article explains it nicely: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs

Also, check your web.Config has these settings:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Yeh, I have it set up to use this, however it just gives me the 404 straight away being served by the StaticFileHandler.  Is there an order of preference somewhere?

Comment: Don't think so - you probably don't want them both active though. I'm running Windows 8 these days so can't take a quick look at the settings in IIS7.5 - you need to make sure that the handler doesn't ensure that the file exists

Comment: Ok, I've even deleted the StaticFile handler module from IIS, which caused the following to be added to my web.config.. <remove name="StaticFile" /> However I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: Is there any reason why you have it set to classic rather than integrated? I know it doesn't answer this question but it should solve the problem

Comment: Yeh we use StructureMap for dependency injection and when integrated is switched on we get the following StructureMap exception: StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily My.Namespace.IMyInterface

Comment: Have you considered popping that one on to SO as well? 2 pronged attack so to speak. This might help: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/01/22/advanced-structuremap-diagnosing-problems/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23138/discussion-between-lisburnite-and-levelnis)